# jQuery check input value and show warning based on value

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to display a warning for the user when they enter a date that is before today. When this happens I want to display this span tag. I also need to check if the span is already there so I don't add it again.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$('[name="input_name"]').blur(function(){
        var today = new Date();
        var hiredate = new Date(value);
        if (hiredate < today) {
        $(this).after("<span class='date_warning'>Warning hire</span>");
    }
    else{
        $('span').remove('.date_warning');
    }
});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `this.value` instead of `value`

*Change*

```
var hiredate = new Date(value);
```

*To*

```
var hiredate = new Date(this.value);
```

Comment: Awesome looks like this is working. I'm having issue with the duplicate span tags though.

Comment: Can you explain what is the issue, adding html could make it easy to understand and reach the solution

Comment: Here is the HTML I have right now - <fieldset>
 <label>Hire Date</label>
 <input type="text" name="input_name" />
</fieldset>

Comment: Right this is the version before the warning is added. Here is the js that I can't get working correctly. else {
   $(this).parent().find('span').remove();
  }

Comment: Add html to your question.

Comment: Here is the total HTML <fieldset><label>Hire Date</label><input type="text" name="input_name"/><span class="date_warning">Warning Hire</span></fieldset>

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
$('[name="input_name"]').blur(function(){
        var today = new Date();
        var hiredate = new Date($(this).val());
        if (hiredate < today) {
        $(this).next('.date_warning').remove();
        $(this).after("<span class='date_warning'>Warning hire</span>");
    }
    else{
        $(this).next('.date_warning').remove();
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TBLp8/1/)

try changing value in input field

Comment: awesome this is working but I am still getting the duplicate span tags

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('[name="input_name"]').blur(function(){
    $('.date_warning').remove();
    var today = new Date();
    var hiredate = new Date(this.value);
    if (hiredate < today) {
        $(this).after("<span class='date_warning'>Warning hire</span>");
    }
});
```